# Delete all empty folders in Pimcore 10.5 Data Object via PHP

Tags: pimcore

I've a PHP command which reads data from an external source and inserts data in Pimcore 10.5 as Data Objects.

This procedure leaves behind a few empty Pimcore Data Object **folder**.

Is there a built-in Pimcore procedure to remove all empty folders programmatically or should I just traverse the tree and remove them on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own code:

```php
    protected function removeEmptyFolders() : static
    {
        $this->fxTitle("Removing empty folder(s)...");

        $oFolders = Folder::getList([
            'condition' => "o_type = 'folder' AND o_parentId > 0"
        ])->load();

        $folderNum = count($oFolders);

        if( $folderNum == 0 ) {

            $this->fxWarning("No folders detected!");
            return $this;
        }

        $this->fxInfo("##$folderNum## folder(s) loaded");

        $arrFolderByPath = [];
        foreach($oFolders as $folder) {

            $path = $folder->getPath() . $folder->getKey() . "/";
            $arrFolderByPath[$path] = $folder;
        }

        //
        $oDataObjects = Folder::getList([
            'condition' => "o_parentId > 0"
        ])->load();

        foreach($oDataObjects as $folder) {

            $path = $folder->getPath();
            if( array_key_exists($path, $arrFolderByPath) && $folder->getId() != $arrFolderByPath[$path]->getId() ) {
                unset($arrFolderByPath[$path]);
            }
        }

        $folderNum = count($arrFolderByPath);
        if( $folderNum == 0 ) {

            $this->fxInfo("No empty folders detected");
            return $this;
        }

        $this->fxInfo("Deleting ##$folderNum## folder(s)...");

        foreach($arrFolderByPath as $folder) {

            $deletedFolderTitle = implode(' | ', [$folder->getId(), $folder->getPath(), $folder->getKey()]) . PHP_EOL;

            if( $this->isNotDryRun() ) {
                $folder->delete();
            }

            $this->fxOK($deletedFolderTitle);
        }

        if( $this->isDryRun() ) {
            // prevent infinite recursion
            return $this;
        }

        return $this->removeEmptyFolders();
    }
```